# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNullOrUndefined' of undefined from sp.core.js

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, classic-experience

My SharePoint 2019 classic page is not displaying list view webpart items (*refreshing the page for multiple times will show the list view webpart items*). When I checked the browser console found the below error.

[image]

When I checked for the error in sp.core.js , found the below

[image]

Devtools is logging that the error is occurring from the below code (*from function **init_zz10_TopNavigationMenu**. Code is copied from the .aspx page and formatted.*)

```
g_QuickLaunchControlIds.push("zz10_TopNavigationMenu");
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('QuickLaunchInitDroppable');
var g_zz10_TopNavigationMenu = null;

function init_zz10_TopNavigationMenu()
{
    if (g_zz10_TopNavigationMenu == null) g_zz10_TopNavigationMenu = $create(SP.UI.AspMenu, null, null, null, $get('zz10_TopNavigationMenu'));
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init_zz10_TopNavigationMenu, 'SP.Core.js');
```

The only similar issue found in the internet was [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/59dc1dda-ad24-4b19-add7-8d0c7e3f79f2/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-isnullorundefined-of-undefined-in-spcorejs?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Could someone guide me what could be the root cause of this error. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below scripts to the page fixed the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
```